# How the css property display none, and block works in html file?

Tags: html, css, display

This is my code , and running well, but my problem is in the css file, i know the "display"
css properties very well and how it work but below code actually it is a dropdown manu code, {display:none} means nothing will show, and {display:block} is used for only inline elements. Now my Question is for which hidden properties of display when i hovering to DropDown button it will show me the manu,s?

```css
#o2 li a{ background-color: burlywood}

ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
#o2 li:hover .mainbtn{
    background-color: yellow;
}
#o2 li .dpbtn{
    display: none;
}
#o2 li:hover .dpbtn{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="o2">
    <li><a class="mainbtn" href="#">DropDown</a>
        <div class="dpbtn">
            <a href="#">manu1</a>
            <a href="#">manu1</a>
            <a href="#">manu1</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you describe your question with other words? Hard to understand.

Comment: when hovering , the manu1, manu2 shows, and it works for display block properties, but why? coz we use display block properties for inline elemets.

Comment: "{display:block} is used for only inline elements". No, it isn't.

Comment: "{display:block} is used for only inline elements". No, it isn't. ------describe please why?

Comment: Display block works for all the elements if you are giving this property in case file. There are lots of elements which has block display by default. Like h and p, div and sections ... But if you are making them display none, so may be at some point you need to make them block again.. so display block works inline and on block elements, both.

Comment: The property is used, among other things, to determine if an element is handled as inline or block—what would be the use case for restricting it to inline elements? But of course negative proofs are hard—I cannot just link documentation that doesn't make a given claim.

Comment: Like h and p, div and sections ... But if you are making them display none, so may be at some point you need to make them block again..---------for example: @Atul

Comment: it's clear at all what you are asking. You have an element that you made hidden with display:none then visible again with display:block. What you don't understand here? diplay can be applied to any element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, when we hovering `li` - the `.dpbtn` has properties `display: block;`. When your cursor is on any inside element, for example `a` - you are still hovering `li`, because `a` is inside `li`, the part of it.

[image]

**UPDATED**
.dpbtn is div element. if we don't set any displey property - it will be BLOCK by default, not none
every element is visible by default, if we want to hide it - we should use display none.

After using display none - we should rewrite this behavior for :hover action.

*Display block works for all the elements if you are giving this property in case file. There are lots of elements which has block display by default. Like h and p, div and sections ... But if you are making them display none, so may be at some point you need to make them block again.. so display block works inline and on block elements, both* @Atul

Comment: All elements inside li - part of the il. When you hovering child elements - you are although hovering li at the same time.

Comment: if so, then why we need to used display none first and then display block??????

Comment: display none is hiding .dpbtn , and when we hovering li - the .dpbtn appears. It's so simple, so I even don't know hove to explain. What result so you need to reach?

Comment: as u said display none is hiding .dpbtn , and when we hovering li - the .dpbtn appears. but in hovering u assign display block, why we used their display block whereas u make it none before?

Comment: display block sets by default by browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212564/discussion-between-hadisur-rahman-and-focus-style).

Comment: display block sets by default by browser then why we need it to assign again display block on hovering?

Comment: .dpbtn is div element. if we don't set any displey property - it will be BLOCK by default, not none
every element is visible by default, if we want to hide it - we should use display none.

Comment: When we are hovering - the element is still display none according to you code. We don't have display block by hovering by default